# Are the two-valued homogeneous harmonic functions classified?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, harmonic-functions, geometric-analysis

**Question.** Is there a classification of homogeneous two-valued harmonic functions on $\mathbf{R}^n$, valid in dimensions $n \geq 3$?

For reference, multi-valued functions are familiar objects in complex analysis. They work like the usual (single-valued) functions, except they are allowed to return several values. When one allows exactly two values, one speaks of *two-valued functions*. The protoypical examples are the complex roots:
\begin{equation}
(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbf{R}^2 \mapsto \mathrm{Re}(x_1 + \mathrm{i} x_2)^{Q/2},
\end{equation}
where $3 \leq Q \in \mathbf{Z}$ is an odd integer.

The functions $u$ we consider are *harmonic* in the sense that both branches are harmonic away from the branch set, and *homogeneous* in the sense that $u(tx_1,tx_2) = t^\mu u(x_1,x_2)$ for all $t > 0, x \in \mathbf{R}^2$ and some $\mu \in \mathbf{R}$. (See below for additional information on harmonicity in the two-valued setting.)

The root functions described above are basically the only examples of homogeneous harmonic two-valued functions on $\mathbf{R}^2$. To be precise one needs to consider \begin{equation} x \mapsto \mathrm{Re}((a+\mathrm{i} b) (x_1 + \mathrm{i} x_2))^{Q/2} \quad \text{where $a,b \in \mathbf{R}$} \end{equation}
for a complete classification in dimension $n = 2$.

This brings me to the stated question, which can be reformulated as follows.

**Question'.** Is a classification available in higher dimensions, for example when $n = 3$ or $n = 4$? Single-valued homogeneous harmonic functions are polynomials.  Perhaps the two-valued harmonic functions could be their 'roots' in a way analogous to the above?

**Edit.** Expressed in symbols, the harmonicity of a two-valued function $C^1$-regular $u$ say on a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ would be defined as follows. Let $K_u \subset \Omega$ be the complement of the set of all points $x \in \Omega$ near which $u$ can be decomposed into two transverse $C^1$-regular branches. To be exact for such $x$ there is $r > 0$ and $u_{1},u_{2} \in C^1(D_r(x))$ so that first $u = \{ u_{1}, u_{2} \}$ on $D_r(x)$ and second either $u_1(x) \neq u_2(x)$ or $Du_1(x) \neq Du_2(x)$. Then one says that $u$ is *harmonic* if around all points $x \in \Omega \setminus K_u$, both branches $u_{1},u_{2}$ are harmonic.

This definition is used for example in the works of Leon Simon, Neshan Wickramasekera, Brian Krummel and their collaborators [1,2]. One motivation for two-and multi-valued harmonic functions in this context is that they arise as blow-ups of singular minimal surfaces near branch points. The first person to use $Q$-valued functions was Frederick Almgren in his regularity theory of area-minimising currents [3]; see also a series of papers by Camillo de Lellis and Emanuele Spadaro on this topic. Technically the functions studied there are so-called $\mathrm{Dir}$-minimising, but I believe if they are $C^{1,\alpha}$-regular then they are also harmonic in the sense above.

Finally, to the best of my knowledge a similar approach is chosen for example in the definition of $\mathbf{Z}/2$ harmonic spinors [4], although this is beyond my area of expertise.

[1] Simon L., Wickramasekera N. *A frequency function and singular set bounds for branched minimal immersions.* Communications in Pure and Applied Mathematics, Vol. 69, 1213-1258 (2016).
[2] Krummel B. *Existence and regularity of solutions to multivalued elliptic equations and systems.* Comm. Anal. Geom. Vol. 4, 877-835 (2019).
[3] Almgren, Frederick J., Jr. *Almgren's big regularity paper.
Q-valued functions minimizing Dirichlet's integral and the regularity of area-minimizing rectifiable currents up to codimension 2.* World Scientific Monograph Series in Mathematics, 1. (2000)
[3] Taubes C.H.. *The zero loci of $\mathbf{Z}/2$ harmonic spinors in dimension 2,3 and 4*. (2014) arXiv: 1407.6206.

Comment: You should give more precise definition of a 2-valued harmonic function. (In what exact sense your example is harmonic at $0$)? You cannot simply say "harmonic except at the origin", since $R^n\backslash\{0\}$ for $n\geq 3$ is simply connected, and every multi-valued analytic function in a simply connected region is in fact single valued (by monodromy theorem).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko With all due respect, I think you might have misread the definition. Note in particular that nowhere is it mentioned that they be "harmonic except at the origin". In any case I have added some details that I hope will clear up any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Has anyone studied such functions? What can the branch locus be?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes, they have been studied, in particular in relation to the regularity of minimal surfaces near branch points, starting with Almgren. Their branch set has Hausdorff dimension $n-2$. There is also a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0923) by Wickramasekera and Krummel that establishes finer properties like rectifiability.

Comment: So, in case of two valued function, the sum of the branches is ordinary harmonic function, and the branch set must be a union of rays from the origin, correct?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes, the average is an ordinary, meaning single-valued harmonic function. When the function is homogeneous, then the branch set indeed consists of rays, although when $n \geq 4$ there would be uncountably many.